# If $ T(f)=\int_0^12xf(x)\,dx$ find the value of $||T||$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let , $T:(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty})\to \mathbb R  $ be defined by $\displaystyle T(f)=\int_0^12xf(x)\,dx$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$. Then find $||T||$, where , $\displaystyle ||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{0\le x\le 1}|f(x)|$.

We have , $\displaystyle |T(f)|\le 2\int_0^1x\,dx=1$. Then , $||T||\le 1$
.  I am unable to find the converse inequality...

Comment: You have $Tf = \int_0^1 f(x)dx^{2}$, which is integration with respect to a positive measure. The norm of $\|T\|$ is the variation of the measure (this works for signed and even complex Borel measures,) and the variation of a positive measure is the total measure $\int_0^1 dx^{2}=1$. So the solution posted below is general: use $T(1)$ to obtain the norm whenever the representing measure is positive.

Answer (score 2):

Take the constant function $f(x)=1$ to show that $||T||=1$.

Comment: Why take a particular function ?

Comment: @Panja717 : because it works. If for a function $f$, you have $\frac{\|Tf\|}{\|f\|} = 1$, then obviously $\| T\| \geq 1$

Comment: @uniquesolution  $|T(f)|\le 2\int_0^1|xf(x)|\,dx \le 2 \int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx \le 2\|f\|_{\infty}\int_0^1 dx$

Comment: from this, I can  say that $\|T\| \le 2$

Comment: I don't know , how did user181525 prove $\|T\| \le 1$?